# Translucent plastic film wrapping object

Tags: modeling, rendering, edit-mode

I created a coil,

I want to add a layer of plastic packaging to it.

I just started learning blender,

I don't know how to implement it, please help me!

This is my model.

[image]
[image]

I want to achieve this effect.

[image]

How do I achieve it?

Comment: I really suggest to look up a YouTube video on this, rather then asking for advice here. Although this is a really good question, it has been displayed many times on other sites with really good explanations on this. However try adding Cloth physics and have weight points around the object then set up individual materiel and texture properties.

Regards,